# Create and Add Passpoint configuration profile programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, config

I am building an application in which I called an api and get files (containing details like SSID and pass phrases) from server.

I need to make a config file and add this config file into my iPhone.

After that depend on the requirement connect as well.

But I am stuck to how to add it programmatically not using even not able to make the file.

Comment: What's going into the config file? user input? Then you maybe should use the user defaults system... Or even sensible data? Then Keychain is the better option. Please tell us more about your use case.

Comment: Config file contains the SSID and network details.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Can you add some code that shows what you are trying to do and the problem you are having?  Are you just asking if, conceptually, what you want to do is possible?

Comment: I am asking that i had .mobileconfig file which i have to add without user intervation, only by programmatically in to my app.

Comment: There's no way of doing it without user interventions. User has to redirect to Safari or Mail app to install profile manually.